# Why my top menu dissappear when in register or reset page in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla

I have created a custom joomla template based on blank joomla template from http://blank.vc/. Everything was fine until i clicked either forgot password?, forgot your username? or create account link that bring me to register or reset page in frontend but strangely the top menu was gone.

This is the screenshot :
http://i63.photobucket.com/albums/h145/affan2fly/menugone.jpg

i have no idea why this could happenned.

Please help with this. I appreciate all the help. Thanks!

Comment: is top menu module assigned for all pages?

Comment: Yes, i have assigned on every pages

Comment: did you assign it by checking "only on the pages selected" and then selecting all menus, or by checking "on all pages"?

Comment: only on the pages selected and then selecting all menus. actually i have two main menus, because this site is in two languages. and not only my top menu is gone, but my breadcrumbs module under the top menu is gone too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because `only on the pages selected` option for module assignment is set. If you open a page which doesn't belong to any menu, then module won't be shown on it.

You can either check menu module to be shown `on all pages`, or make a new menu item for `forgot password` functionality, and then assign that menu for both menu module, and breadcrumbs module.

I don't know which Joomla version you're using and what you use for translation, but if you use Joomfish or Falang, language translation should be much easier.

If you don't use any of those, and you really need to leave everything as it is, then you can also detect current user language in the template, and load either one or the other menu module based on it. That way you can set module to be shown on all pages, and make sure it is displayed only for the choosen language.

Comment: Yes Finally i have found it. Thanks Marko, i have re-assigned those modules to "on all pages except selected".